# How Laravel defines name of the foreign-key as default in Model file?

Tags: laravel, model, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

I am new at Laravel and I am wondering how actually Laravel determines default foreign key name.

According to the Laravel document, it says `"Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with _id"`.

Then, in this case↓, the default foreign key supposed to be named as  `info_id` as the document says.

`app/Models/Item.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Item extends Model
{
   public function itemInfo()
   {
       return $this->hasOne(‘App\Models\ItemInfo’);
   }
}
```

I just changed the name of `info`function as `infooo` THEN, no error happened. It do works...
What I expected was an error occurs because I thought Laravel would name the default foreign key as `infooo_id` and there is not such a column name in the tables.
It means Laravel does not determine the default foreign key name by the method name, doesn`t it?

**Then what portion actually Laravel determine the default foreign key from?**

These are the migration files of tables:

`database/YYYY_MM_dd_hhiiss_create_items_table.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateItemsTable extends Migration
{
   /**
    * Run the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function up()
   {
       Schema::create(‘items’, function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->increments(‘id’);
           $table->string(‘name’);
           $table->timestamps();
       });
   }

   /**
    * Reverse the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function down()
   {
       Schema::dropIfExists(‘items’);
   }
}
```

`YYYY_mm_dd_hhiiss_create_item_infos_table.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateItemInfosTable extends Migration
{
   /**
    * Run the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function up()
   {
       Schema::create(‘item_infos’, function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->increments(‘id’);
           $table->integer(‘item_id’)->unsigned();
           $table->string(‘genre’);
           $table->timestamps();
       });
   }

   /**
    * Reverse the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function down()
   {
       Schema::dropIfExists(‘item_infos’);
   }
}
```

Comment: I could't see your foreign key in your migration...after integer(‘item_id’)

Comment: Thanks for the comment!
I was trying to set the foreign key in the Model file: `Item.php` not in the migration file, so I think I don't have to determine the foreign key name in the migration file...
And I know that I can determine the foreign key name manually on the second argument of hasOne() in `Item.php`. but I do want to know how actually Laravel determines the default foreign key name since it seems to determine the name not from the relation-function name but somewhere. I want to know where "somewhere" is.